# Contar id's distintos de 2 tablas usando join

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT count(distinct a.H_C) FROM A1 a
full outer join A2 b on a.H_C=b.H_C
```

DONDE: H_C, es el código (ambiguo), age_range: es el rango de edad; tanto en la tabla A1 como en la A2; como resultado necesitaria la cuenta de las H_C de ambas tablas sin repetirse.

Gracias de antemano por sus prontas respuestas, trate de implementar lo sugerido , para unir estos 2 querys pero no pude realizarlo; este caso el objetivo es que cuente las H_C distintas, espero que puedan ayudarme, gracias.

```
SELECT sexo, age_range, Count(DISTINCT(H_C)) as total
FROM ( Select H_C, 
CASE
WHEN ANNOS <=0  then '01'
WHEN ANNOS between 1 and 4   then '02' WHEN ANNOS between 5 and 9   then '03'
ELSE ANNOS END as age_range,SEXO FROM A1
WHERE PERIODO='2019') t
GROUP BY SEXO,age_range ORDER BY SEXO desc,age_range asc
--UNION
SELECT sexo, age_range, Count(DISTINCT(H_C)) as total
FROM ( Select H_C, 
CASE
WHEN ANNOS <=0  then '01'
WHEN ANNOS between 1 and 4   then '02' WHEN ANNOS between 5 and 9   then '03'
ELSE ANNOS END as age_range,SEXO FROM A2
WHERE PERIODO='2019') t
GROUP BY SEXO,age_range ORDER BY SEXO desc,age_range
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
SELECT distinct H_C FROM A1
union
select distinct H_C from A2
```

o

```
SELECT distinct H_C from (
    select H_C FROM A1
    union 
    select H_C FROM A2
) HC
```

Comment: `UNION` entrega sólo resultados distintos, por lo que el `DISTINCT` no es necesario

Answer (score 0):

Esto te diría la cantidad de `ID` distintos de cada una de las tablas, coincidan o no entre ambas

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT a.H_C) AS 'Cod',
        COUNT(DISTINCT b.H_C) AS 'A2'
    FROM Cod
    FULL OUTER JOIN A2 b 
        ON a.H_C=b.H_C
```

Si buscas los coincidentes:

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT a.H_C) AS 'Cod/A2'
    FROM Cod
    INNER JOIN A2 b 
        ON a.H_C=b.H_C
```